# SQLITE_OK equating to 1

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, ios4

i am seeing some strange behavior, that I can't explain in xcode 3.2.5 when trying to use sqlite for iphone development.

If I execute the following statement, code goes to code block 1, but value of rc=1
SQLITE_OK is constant with value 0
shouldn't rc=0 if code block 1 is executing?

```
int rc;
if(rc=sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &pStmt, 0) == SQLITE_OK){
    //code block 1
}
```

What am I missing? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`==` is higher precedence than `=`, so it's doing the comparison first, then assigning the result, 1, to `rc`. You need to wrap the assignment in parentheses:

```
if ((rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &pStmt, 0)) == SQLITE_OK)
```